# How to order members of a class if there are static members too?

Tags: c++, optimization

I know that order in declaration of the members of a class matters for using less memory (descending order based on type size). E.g.: `class A { int x; double y; int z; };` will use more memory than `class A { double y; int x; int z; };`

Is this still true for the latest compilators (I use Ubuntu)? If yes, where shall I put the static members?

```
class A
{
private:
  static int m1;
  double m2;
  int m3;

public:
// ...
};
```

Where shall I place m1 in this place for using less memory?

Comment: Um, I guess it has no effect - it might affect on only instance members

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that your example probably gives the same sizes for each. A better case: `class A { int32_t x; int64_t y; int32_t z; };` and `class A { int32_t x; int32_t z; int64_t y; };`.

Comment: Them pesky compilators.

Comment: @JosephMansfield I have done the edit, sorry for not a good example

Comment: Please stop writing tags in titles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard

> A static data member is not part of the subobjects of a class.

So they may have even incomplete types in the class definition. They do not influence on the size of a class.

Comment: I think it would be nice to explain _subobjects_. As is, I guess that a significant amount of people not familiar in C++ Standardese will think of derived classes and then be confused.

Comment: @phresnel In this case this means simply data members of the class that is member subobjects.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: He means to explain it _in your answer_.

Answer (score 2):

Static data members are not stored in the class instances; instead you get *one instance* of each one, and these "live" in the place where you defined them.

```
struct A
{
  static int m1;
  double m2;
  int m3;
};

int A::m1; // <--- this lives here!
```

As such, the position of their declaration within the definition of `A` is entirely immaterial for the padding, alignment and ordering of `A`'s non-static data members.